# Chunking input string into number of characters per line java programming

Tags: java, string, input

I am trying to write a java code that takes as input a string and a chunk size, and it chops the string into chunks of the given size.  Note that the last chunk may be smaller than the size requested. Heres an example of what the output would look like:

```
String? abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Chunk size? 4
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yz
```

I cannot figure this out, I have been working on it for quite some times, so here I am.

This is the code that I have right now, but a lot has been moved around just to try:

```
package Oct_27_2014;

import java.util.Scanner;   

public class ChunkingAPhrase {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // declare variables
    int chunkNumber;
    String phrase;
    int start = 0;

    // get input
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("String? ");
    phrase = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Chunk size? ");
    chunkNumber = scan.nextInt();

    // parse string

    while(start < phrase.length()) {
        String chunks = phrase.substring(start, chunkNumber);
        start++;


        if (phrase.indexOf(chunkNumber) != start) {
            System.out.println(chunks);
            System.out.println();

        }else{

        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the output I get for this code:

```
String? abcdefg12345
Chunk size? 3
abc
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

bc

c
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at Oct_27_2014.ChunkingAPhrase.main(ChunkingAPhrase.java:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `substring` method requires you to specify a start index and an end index for the chunk that you want to extract, not a start index and a length.  So you need to work out what the end index should be.  It might be the start index plus the length of a chunk, or the current chunk might go all the way to the end of the string.  Lastly, the start index for the next iteration will be the end index of the current iteration.

So replace your `while` loop with this.  I don't think anything else needs to change.  Good luck.

```
while (start < phrase.length()) {
    int end = start + chunkNumber;
    if (end > phrase.length()) {
        end = phrase.length();
    }

    System.out.println(phrase.substring(start, end));
    start = end; 
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and made sense. Just want to say thank you, I worked too long on trying to figure that out!

Comment: You're very welcome, @Emily.  Best of luck with your learning.